# How to display single post in React

Tags: api, reactjs, redux

I was following a tutorial and now I'm trying to make my own blog, but it gives me the following error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ] (28:28)

  26 | 
  27 | function mapStateToProps({contacts}, ownProps) {
> 28 |   return (contact: contacts[ownProps.match.params.id])
     |                             ^
  29 | }
```

I have a page with all the contacts and when I click on the contact name, I want to show a page with full details. The backend should be working because it gives back the correct user (I tested it with Postman).

Here is my `ContactShow.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { fetchContact } from '../../actions';

class ContactShow extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.fetchContact(id);
    }
    render() {
        const { contact } = this.props;

        if (!contact) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {contact.contactTitle} {contact.contactName}
                <br />
                {contact.contactAddress}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({contacts}, ownProps) {
  return (contact: contacts[ownProps.match.params.id])
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchContact})(ContactShow)
```

Here is the `actions/index.js`:

```
export const fetchContact = (id) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get(`/api/contacts/${id}`)

    dispatch({type: FETCH_CONTACT, payload: res.data.contact})
}
```

And the reducer part related to fetching the contact:

```
case FETCH_CONTACT:
  return {...state, [action.payload.data.id]: action.payload.data};
```

Just to confirm, when I write in Postman `GET localhost:5000/api/contacts/59c7b975d9d7eed098507a64` I get the following json:

```
{
  "contact": {
    "_id": "59c7b975d9d7eed098507a64",
    "contactTitle": "Mrs",
    "contactName": "Lisa",
    "contactEmail": "lisa@hexample.com",
    "contactTelephone": "12345678",
    "contactAddress": "Example Road, 12",
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of '(' try '{' in your mapStateToProps

```
function mapStateToProps({contacts}, ownProps) {
  return {contact: contacts[ownProps.match.params.id]}
}
```

Comment: Great pickup! But now I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`

Comment: @Al-josh That means `ownProps.match` does not exist. I suggest you throw a debugger into your `mapStateToProps` and see what `ownProps` actually looks like.